# How to find all polynomials $p \in \Bbb C [x]$ such that $x^3 p'(x) = p(x)^2$?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, complex-numbers

> How to find all polynomials $p \in \Bbb C [x]$ such that $x^3 p'(x) = p(x)^2$?

Since $\operatorname{degree}(p(x)) = y$, and $\operatorname{degree}\left(p'(x)\right) = y-1$, I tried to deduce what degree the polynomial should have. If $\operatorname{degree}(p(x))=2$, then $\operatorname{degree}(p(x)^2)=4$. And $\operatorname{degree}(p'(x))=1$, then $\operatorname{degree}(x^3 p'(x))=4$. So the polynomial should have degree $2$.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach. How can I complete the proof from this point?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Suppose that $p$ is degree-$d$.  Then, $x^3 p'$ should be degree-$(d+2)$ and $p^2$ should be degree-$2d$, right?

Comment: "*If grade(p(x))=2*" $\;-\;$ You can't solve it by guessing degrees. But, with your notations, the degree of $p^2$ is $2y$ and the degree of $p'$ is $y-1$ so you have $3+(y-1)=2y$. Solve it for $y$, then notice that $x^3$ on the LHS must divide $p^2(x)$ on the RHS.

Comment: Alternately: solve that simple (first-order, separable) differential equation, and look to see if any of the solutions are polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $p$ is degree-$d$. Then, $x^3 p'$ should be degree-$(d+2)$ and $p^2$ should be degree-$2d$. Thus, $\color{blue}{d=2}$. Let

$$ p (x) = c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 $$

Using [SymPy](https://sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> c0, c1, c2 = symbols('c0 c1 c2')
>>> p = c0 + c1 * x + c2 * x**2
>>> q = x**3 * diff(p,x) - p**2
>>> collect(q.expand(), x)
-c0**2 - 2*c0*c1*x + x**4*(-c2**2 + 2*c2) + x**3*(-2*c1*c2 + c1) + x**2*(-2*c0*c2 - c1**2)
```

Hence, $c_0 = c_1 = 0$.  What can you tell about the coefficient $c_2$? $\color{white}{\text{Would you agree that } c_2 \in \{0,2\} \text{?}}$

Comment: I don't get why c0=c1=0 from the explanation. c2 should be either 0 or 2 since those are the only numbers where 2(c2)=c2^2

Comment: @Juan Take a look at the coefficients of $x^0$ and $x^2$